# Slide show - how to autorun manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Is there a way to automatically run a manipulate command when you move to a slide ? I am trying to create a presentation and i have a number of slides which have use manipulate and i want these to run/loop when this slide is showing ?

Thanks
David.

Comment: `AutorunSequencing` may yield part of the functionality you're looking for. The `Manipulate` [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html) has some sections on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you can replace your Manipulate command by Animate this is easy to accomplish. Have a look at the Help page of Animate to see if you can configure the behaviour in the way you want it.
For example the following animation can be placed on a slide and will be started automatically if you got to that slide:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 1, 2 Pi}], {a, 1, 10}]
```

Hope this helps.